# Firebase email authentication?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

I'm trying to use firebase (email authentication) for my android app. I don't recieve any error msg., but It doesn't work. I'm stuck somewhere and I cant solve. I need your help. Thanks.

- Package name same (firebase and app).
- I imported json file in project app folder.
- SIGN-IN METHOD = Email/Password = Enabled

Database rule published:

```
 {
  "rules": {
         ".read": true,
         ".write": true,
  }
}
```

This is build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypack.kim"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
```

Login class :

```
package com.mypack.kim;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.firebase.client.AuthData;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.mypack.ream.R;

public class Loginme  extends Activity {

    Button btLog;
    EditText edUser,edPass;
    public static Firebase firejo;
    String email,pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_pg);
        btLog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLog);
        edUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edUser);
        edPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edPass);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firejo = new Firebase("https://try-ad555.firebaseio.com/");
        btLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                email = edUser.getText().toString();
                pass = edPass.getText().toString();
                login(email, pass);
            }
        });
    }

    public void login(final String email, String pass) {
        firetunc.authWithPassword(email, pass, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                Intent istat = new Intent(Loginme.this, Main_Page.class);
                startActivity(istat);
            }
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a new detail tutorial at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth  which may help. I can see gradle dependencies missing as well as handling authentication in Activity class.

Comment: Where did you create your project? If you created it on firebase.google.com, it will not work with Firebase Authentication 2.x (which you're using in your gradle script).

Comment: Thank my friends. But I didn't solve yet. I created with netbeans after than migrated android studio. I confused, should I use json file and  Android studio doesn't find 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0' this.

Comment: https://github.com/Balaviknesh/Android-FirebaseLogin try this example. It's the latest one, it may help you.